# Convert date to Unix time without os.time()

Tags: date, time, lua

I am developing a plugin written in Lua, and I need a way to calculate Unix time or at least a way to compare 2 date strings.

The function I can use only returns date string in the following format

```
"1/17/2014 6:50 PM"
```

Is there a way to convert this string to a Unix time?

Unfortunately I don't have access to the OS library so things like `os.time()` do not work.

Is there any library or something similar that I can work with?
I also thought about splitting the string into parts, but I need a way to add/subtract time

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/DateAndTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare normalized timestamps:

```
function normalize(a)
    local m,d,y,h,mi,n=a:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)%s+(%d+):(%d+)%s+(%w+)")
    if n=="PM" then h=h+12 end
    return string.format("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d",y,m,d,h,mi)
end
```

Date arithmetic is another story. For a complete, pure Lua date library, see [luatz](https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz)  or https://github.com/Tieske/date.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only compare two time, you don't need to get each time's Unix timestamp. One possible solution is to get the time fields from the string like this:

```
local time = "1/17/2014 6:50 PM"
local month, day, year, hour, minute, am_pm = time:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)%s+(%d+):(%d+)%s+(%w+)")

print(month, day, year, hour, minute, am_pm)
```

Output: `1       17      2014    6       50      PM`

Then compare two time from comparing their `year`, if they are equal, then `month`, and so on. Remember to use `tonumber` to compare them by number, not the string itself.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I also need a way to calculate something like : 20 minutes later from now, 1 month later from now etc. Thats why I was sticking to UNIX timestamp

Comment: @user3199786 Using `os.time()` to get the timestamp, I know you said you don't have it, but you can write it in C yourself. (The official source code is [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#os_time). Another way is to write one in Lua, google for the Unix time formula.